# Grails run-app or grails compile is not working with 6..0.0( java 11 or 17)

Tags: groovy, grails, compilation, run-app

The steps I followed to get the error -

1. Installed grails 6.0.0 or 6.1.2 installed, and either java 11 or 17 respectively
2. grails create-app myapp
3. Move to myapp directory.
4. grails run-app

The received error message is -

Unmatched argument at index 0: 'run-app'
Did you mean: grails create-app or grails create-webapp or grails create-restapi?

Answer (score 3):

From the "Getting started" documentation:

https://docs.grails.org/6.1.2/guide/gettingStarted.html#_step_6_run_the_application

> Grails framework now relies on Gradle tasks for running the application. To start the application, use the following Gradle bootRun command:
>
> `$ ./gradlew bootRun`
>
> Your application will be hosted on port 8080 by default.